# Flutter - mensagem só é envia se todos os campos estiver preenchido

Tags: flutter, dart

Quando tento enviar uma mensagem sem imagem, o mailer apresenta erro, mas se eu tirar o campo       ***..attachments.add(new FileAttachment(_imagemAn,));*** a mensagem é enviada normalmente sem apresentar o erro, porém, o engraçado e que não estou conseguindo é que, se nessa mesma mensagem que estava dando erro por ser enviada sem imagem, contendo ***..attachments.add(new FileAttachment(_imagemAn,));***, é somente adicionar uma imagem e a mensagem é enviada.

é quase como se eu fosse forçado a enviar com imagem, preciso dizer que ***..attachments.add(new FileAttachment(_imagemAn,));*** igual ou diferente de nulo?

Estou suando a API do mailer: ^4.0.0.

De forma mais direta, quando a mensagem só é envia se todos os campos estiver preenchido, se um dos campos não for preenchido a mensagem não  enviada, como corrigir?

Esse é o código que estou usando, esta é a tela onde é visualizada a mensagem antes de enviar, como uma pagina de confirmação antes do envio.

```
class PaginadeBoasVindasAN extends StatelessWidget {

  String _localAn;
  String _problemaAn;
  File _imagemAn;
  File _imagemGaleriaAn;

  PaginadeBoasVindasAN(
    this._localAn,
    this._problemaAn,
    this._imagemAn,
    this._imagemGaleriaAn,
  );

  // Aqui vamos criar o e-mail - smtp

  enviarMensagem() async {
    String username = '@gmail.com';
    String password = '@#';

    final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
    
    final message = Message()
      ..from = Address('Sem identificação', ' ')
      ..recipients.add('@gmail.com')
      ..ccRecipients.addAll(['destCc1@gmail.com', 'destCc1@gmail.com'])
      ..bccRecipients.add(Address('destCc1@gmail.com'))
      ..subject = '$_localAn :: ${DateTime.now()}'
      ..text = 'LOCAL: $_localAn,n\: $_problemaAn'
      ..attachments.add(FileAttachment(_imagemAn,))
      ..attachments.add(FileAttachment(_imagemGaleriaAn,));


    try {
      final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
      print('Mensagem enviada: ' + sendReport.toString());
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print('Mensagem não enviada.');
      for (var p in e.problems) {
        print('Problema: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
      }
    }
    var connection = PersistentConnection(smtpServer);

    await connection.send(message);

    await connection.close();
  }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, mas vamos lá... Se você quer que a imagem seja opcional para envio, é preciso que você faça uma condição para enviar ou não a mesma, por exemplo `if (_imageAn != null) message.FileAttachment(_imagemAn,)`. Caso  o contrário nem chama essa função, pois o `FileAttachment` vai tentar criar algo que não existe.

Comment: Me desculpe pela confusão na mensagem, mas você me apresentou algo que eu acredito que vai dá certo, sou novato e estudando por conta, com eu implementaria esta condição ao meu código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você está começando, deixo como dica, que vá um pouco de cada vez, tente entender um poquinho mais sobre alguns pontos do Framework e da linguagem.

No seu código, basta que você trate os dados da imagem para saber se deve ou não informá-la, faça o seguinte:

```
class PaginadeBoasVindasAN extends StatelessWidget {

  String _localAn;
  String _problemaAn;
  File _imagemAn;
  File _imagemGaleriaAn;

  PaginadeBoasVindasAN(
    this._localAn,
    this._problemaAn,
    this._imagemAn,
    this._imagemGaleriaAn,
  );

  // Aqui vamos criar o e-mail - smtp

  enviarMensagem() async {
    String username = '@gmail.com';
    String password = '@#';

    final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
    
    final message = Message()
      ..from = Address('Sem identificação', ' ')
      ..recipients.add('@gmail.com')
      ..ccRecipients.addAll(['destCc1@gmail.com', 'destCc1@gmail.com'])
      ..bccRecipients.add(Address('destCc1@gmail.com'))
      ..subject = '$_localAn :: ${DateTime.now()}'
      ..text = 'LOCAL: $_localAn,n\: $_problemaAn';

     if ((_imageAn != null) && (_imageAn != ""))
       message.attachments.add(FileAttachment(_imagemAn,));
     if ((_imagemGaleriaAn!= null) && (_imagemGaleriaAn!= ""))
       message.attachments.add(FileAttachment(_imagemGaleriaAn,));


    try {
      final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
      print('Mensagem enviada: ' + sendReport.toString());
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print('Mensagem não enviada.');
      for (var p in e.problems) {
        print('Problema: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
      }
    }
    var connection = PersistentConnection(smtpServer);

    await connection.send(message);

    await connection.close();
  }
```

## Explicação

Seu código falha, pois você tenta instânciar um `FileAttachment()` com um caminho inválido ou até mesmo NULO.

## Info

Utilizar os `..` apenas facilita seu código, para que você não precise ficar fazer sempre

```
message.metodoX()
message.metodoY()
message.metodoZ()
```

Podendo apenas fazer

```
message = Message()
..metodoX()
..metodoY()
..metodoZ()
```

Comment: Matheus, obrigado! Literalmente me salvou, não somente com um direcionamento para estudar, mas também me auxiliando com este meu problema!

Comment: Comprei um cursinho na Udemy para aprender a linguagem, mas embora eu tenha aprendido o Dart, tenho dificuldade em usar a linguagem dentro do framework em algumas situações, esta foi uma delas.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado, se a resposta lhe serviu (E caso não queira esperar outras) favor marcar a resposta como aceita.

Comment: Novamente, obrigado!

Comment: Boa noite Matheus, tudo bem contigo? Desculpa incomodar, mas estou com um problema naquela área do código aonde  os foi adicionado os if (no código que me passou ), do nada ele começou a retornar dos dois erros seguintes: Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError (Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null) e o outro erro é esse Exception has occurred.SmtpMessageValidationException (Invalid message..

Comment: Já tentei de tudo, mas não tenho êxito em nada do que eu faço para tentar resolver o problema, nem encontrei ninguém com problema semelhante, algo que fale sobre na biblioteca e etc...

Comment: Esses são problemas relacionados a tentar colocar um valor incorreto numa variável, tu pode ter mudado algo sem perceber, reveja seu código. Não tem muito a ver com as condicionais (IF)

Comment: Obrigado Matheus! Não consegui encontrar o valor incorreto , mas como havia feito o backup do projeto consegui prosseguir!